# How to search for multiple strings and replace them with nothing within a list of strings

Tags: string, r

I have a column in a dataframe like this:

```
npt2$name
#  [1] "Andreas Groll, M.D."
#  [2] ""
#  [3] "Pan-Chyr Yang, PHD"
#  [4] "Suh-Fang Jeng, Sc.D"
#  [5] "Mostafa K Mohamed Fontanet Arnaud"
#  [6] "Thomas Jozefiak, M.D."
#  [7] "Medical Monitor"
#  [8] "Qi Zhu, MD"
#  [9] "Holly Posner"
# [10] "Peter S Sebel, MB BS, PhD Chantal Kerssens, PhD"
# [11] "Lance A Mynderse, M.D."
# [12] "Lawrence Currie, MD"
```

I tried `gsub` but with no luck.
After doing `toupper(x)` I need to replace all instances of 'MD' or 'M.D.' or 'PHD' with nothing.

Is there a nice short trick to do it?

In fact I would be interested to see it done on a single string  and how differently it is done in one command on the whole list.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Regular Expressions since I can simply enumerate all bad strings to be removed. Oh my.... yet another technology (REgEx) to go back to (re-master) :-(

Comment: The field should be only last name, but the data is not consistent. Goal is to end up with only data which is either a last name or first name and remove all academic or other titles

Comment: No need to remaster it - DWin, Justin and Tommy have given all you need to know!  Just copy and paste.  Though regex is one of the more useful things I've learned over the years...

Comment: well. but if I use some code, I need to be sure I understand it and that I do know what I am doing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Either of these:

```
gsub("MD|M\\.D\\.|PHD", "", test)  # target specific strings
gsub("\\,.+$", "", test)        # target all characters after comma
```

Both Matt Parker above and Tommy below have raised the question whether 'M.R.C.P.', 'PhD', 'D.Phil.' and 'Ph.D.' or other British or Continental designations of doctorate level degrees should be sought out and removed. Perhaps @user56 can advise what the intent was.

Comment: @MattParker `sub` does just match the first instance, but its still `vectorized`.  So it'll match the first instance in each element of the vector.

Comment: @Justin Got it, thanks!  I was thinking first-in-vector instead of first-in-string.

Comment: gsub might be better if there were ",MD PHD";s in there. Couldn't tell if all the other acronyms were to be deleted.

Comment: Element 10 in the OP has two names with PhD in them, so `gsub` is required.

Comment: I don't really disagree, although I thought that was a data entry error and "fixed" it in my test scenario.

Comment: if sub is used, then gsub must be used. It must remove all instances of 'MD', not just the first instance (what sub says it does)

Answer (score 3):

With a single ugly regex:

```
 gsub('[M,P].?D.?','',npt2$name)
```

Which says, find characters M or P followed by zero or one character of any kind, followed by a D and zero or one additional character.  More explicitly, you could do this in three steps:

```
npt2$name <- gsub('MD','',npt2$name)
npt2$name <- gsub('M\\.D\\.','',npt2$name)
npt2$name <- gsub('PhD','',npt2name)
```

In those three, what's happening should be more straight forward.  the second replacement you need to "escape" the period since its a special character.

Comment: I like the combined regex, but I think you'd need to specify an optional literal period instead of an optional any-char between the letters - consider "Brian McDonald", for example.

Comment: Touche! but then you miss MD.  If I were doing this data munge I would do it explicitly with one replacement per line for clarity and repeatably. (or DWin's version with logical Ors)

Comment: Would it miss MD?  `gsub('[M,P]\\.?D\\.?', '', "Brian McDonald, MD")` achieves the desired effect, right?

Comment: @MattParker sure does, `?` is one or zero characters.  good point, early still and haven't had my coffee!

Comment: I like the 3 line one. Looks like there is a lot of golfing possible with RegEx code

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant that removes the extra ", " too. Does not require `touppper` either - but if you want that, just specify `ignore.case=TRUE` to `gsub`.

```
test <- c("Andreas Groll, M.D.", 
  "",
  "Pan-Chyr Yang, PHD",
  "Suh-Fang Jeng, Sc.D",
  "Peter S Sebel, MB BS, PhD Chantal Kerssens, PhD",
  "Lawrence Currie, MD")

gsub(",? *(MD|M\\.D\\.|P[hH]D)", "", test)
#[1] "Andreas Groll"                         ""                                     
#[3] "Pan-Chyr Yang"                         "Suh-Fang Jeng, Sc.D"                  
#[5] "Peter S Sebel, MB BS Chantal Kerssens" "Lawrence Currie"
```